# Filtering Multi-Dimensional MDX Query

Tags: ssas, mdx, crosstab

I have an MDX query that drives a Telerik crosstab control that is working as expected:

```
WITH MEMBER [Product].[Product Group Name].[Total] as [Product].[Product Group Name].[All]
select 
NON EMPTY{[Measures].[Annual Premium - Fact Distinct Transaction],
[Measures].[Fact Distinct Transaction Count],
[Measures].[API - Fact Distinct Transaction],
[Measures].[Fact New Members Count]} on columns,
NON EMPTY{
[Product].[Product Group Name].&[Protection],
[Product].[Product Group Name].&[Pension],
[Product].[Product Group Name].&[Savings and Investment],
[Product].[Product Group Name].&[Child Savings],
[Product].[Product Group Name].&[ISA],
[Product].[Product Group Name].[Total]
} on rows,
NON EMPTY{[Region Manager].[Full Name].Children} on 2
,
NON EMPTY{[Transaction Type].[Premium Frequency].&[S],[Transaction Type].[Premium Frequency].&[M]} on 3
from [Cube]
where (
    {StrToMember('[Effective Date].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]'):StrToMember('[Effective Date].[Date].&[2015-09-01T00:00:00]')},
    StrToMember('[Transaction Type].[Transaction Description].[All].[Net Issued]'),
    [Adviser].[Status].&[A]
)
```

I've been asked to exclude

```
WHERE [Product].[Product Group Name].&[Pension] AND [Transaction Type].[Premium Frequency].&[S]
```

and have made an attempt using multiple cross joins, but the solution always seems to be overly lengthy and I'm sure there's a simpler way.

Comment: 4 axes seems a bit much - will this be a sub-select?

Comment: I don't think there is a way I can group the crosstab without the sets being on separate axes.

Comment: what is the point of `on 2` and `on 3` ? Do you have a 4 dimensional monitor?

Comment: This was targeting the Telerik Crosstab control. You would use the dimensions in combination with grouping expressions to have horizontal and vertical calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most satisfactory approach I've found is to use a sub cube:

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY{[Measures].[Annual Premium - Fact Distinct Transaction],
    [Measures].[Fact Distinct Transaction Count],
    [Measures].[API - Fact Distinct Transaction],
    [Measures].[Fact New Members Count]
    } on columns,
    NON EMPTY
    {
    [Product].[Product Group Name].&[Protection],
    [Product].[Product Group Name].&[Pension],
    [Product].[Product Group Name].&[Savings and Investment],
    [Product].[Product Group Name].&[Child Savings],
    [Product].[Product Group Name].&[ISA]
    } on rows,
    NON EMPTY{[Region Manager].[Full Name].Children} on 2,
    NON EMPTY{[Transaction Type].[Premium Frequency].&[S],[Transaction Type].[Premium Frequency].&[M]} on 3
    from
    (
        select
        EXCEPT(
        CROSSJOIN([Product].[Product Group Name].Children, UNION([Transaction Type].[Premium Frequency].&[M] , [Transaction Type].[Premium Frequency].&[S])),
        CROSSJOIN([Product].[Product Group Name].[Pension], [Transaction Type].[Premium Frequency].&[S])
        )on 0
        from [Cube]
    )

WHERE (
    {StrToMember('[Effective Date].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]'):StrToMember('[Effective Date].[Date].&[2015-09-01T00:00:00]')},
    StrToMember('[Transaction Type].[Transaction Description].[All].[Net Issued]'),
    [Adviser].[Status].&[A]
)
```

This means the "Total" figures need to be obtained through a second crosstab that is grouped over the whole set using the same query, as opposed to being a separate member.

Comment: please can you explain the use of axes 2 and 3 - this is not something I have seen before. I realise there are many spare axes that can be used - but other than inside a sub-cube what is the reason for using them is there software that recognises them?

Comment: This was targeting the Telerik Crosstab control. You would use the dimensions in combination with grouping expressions to have horizontal and vertical calculations.